# Not delete embedded objects from Realm

Tags: android, realm

Android Studio 3.2.
Realm 5.8.0

```
    public class Merchant extends RealmObject {
        @PrimaryKey
        private long id;
        private Image preview;
    }

    public class Image extends RealmObject {
        @PrimaryKey
        private long id;
    }
```

I need to delete Merchants object with specific ids AND all it embedded objects (Image in  my example).

So here code:

```
         public static void updateMerchantList(final List<Merchant> thatMerchantsList) {

                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                try {
                    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            RealmList<Merchant> localMerchantList = getMerchantsRealmList();
                            if (!EqualsUtil.areEqualContentLists(localMerchantList, thatMerchantsList)) {
                                List<Merchant> itemNotExistInThatMerchants = new ArrayList<>(localMerchantList);
                                itemNotExistInThatMerchants.removeAll(thatMerchantsList);
                                if (itemNotExistInThatMerchants.size() > 0) {
                                    localMerchantList.removeAll(itemNotExistInThatMerchants);
                                    Long[] idsToDeleteArray = new Long[itemNotExistInThatMerchants.size()];
                                    for (int index = 0; index < itemNotExistInThatMerchants.size(); index++) {
                                        Merchant merchant = itemNotExistInThatMerchants.get(index);
                                        idsToDeleteArray[index] = merchant.getId();
                                    }
                                    RealmResults<Merchant> localMerchantsForDelete = realm.where(Merchant.class).in(Merchant.ID, idsToDeleteArray).findAll();
                                    boolean isDelete = localMerchantsForDelete.deleteAllFromRealm();
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    });
                } finally {
                    realm.close();
                }
            }

 public static RealmList<Merchant> getMerchantsRealmList() {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        try {
            RealmResults<Merchant> realmResults = realm.where(Merchant.class).findAll();
            RealmList<Merchant> realmList = new RealmList<>();
            realmList.addAll(realmResults.subList(0, realmResults.size()));
            return realmList;
        } finally {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
```

As result 2 Merchant success delete from Realm (by method `deleteAllFromRealm`) . 
Nice.

But all embedded objects (like `Image`) **NOT** delete from Realm.

Questions:

- 1. This is because I need to write custom method that **cascade** delete Merchant and all it embedded objects?
- 2. Is Realm can cascade delete objects?

Comment: Killing a Person does not kill their Dog. Therefore, deleting a Merchant does not erase their Image. Cascade behavior is manual.

Comment: And when in Realm implements cascade behavior?

Comment: I can't know that. I only know it depends on Realm Core 6, and certain Sync protocol changes, which was in the making in May, and it's not out yet. I wouldn't wait for it because ***my estimation*** (as a non-Realm person) would be next year April, but nothing is certain.

Comment: I got a `DeleteService.java` to manage every deletion of Realm objects with embedded Realm objects that need to be deleted as well. The cascade deletion would be very nice to have ;)